# Google Drive Contents are not getting displayed when open with selenium on Chrome Browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

**[Gdrive Issue with Selenium Chrome Browser]**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xk3Q.gif)

**Configuration Details:**
Chrome Version Version 72.0.3626.96 
Chrome Driver Version 2.43
Selennium WebDriver 3.11.0

**Issue Description:**

We are able to successfully launch Gdrive with Chrome browser using selenium webdriver till 7 Feb 2019. But now other all apps like Gmail , Google hangout activities working fine on same browser but when opening google drive after page loading we are not getting content of page , We are not able to create folder, Not able to upload file. Only search file working.

Gdrive has some new script introduces as

Comment: look the element selector does that change or same like xpath or id something like that

Comment: After chrome browser launches and Gdrive loaded and login done, then we are not able to perform events manually also

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think that it has to work, it has some Prerequisites for Integration to automate google drive you can also automate google drive api if you want i have shared the link with you it will help you to how to automate google driver or API

https://www.cigniti.com/blog/integrating-selenium-with-google-drive/